# Pandas dates - Convert datetime to date including NaT

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, schema

I'm converting CSVs to parquets and I need the schema to remain consistent. I have datetimes and I'd like to only save as a date. df.column.dt.date seems to work as long as there is at least one datetime, but when the column is all NaT, it remains as a datetime64[ns] type. Code example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "dt1":["2020-02-04","2021-05-02"],
    "dt2":[pd.NaT,pd.NaT],
    "dt3":[pd.NaT,"2020-03-26"]
})
df["dt1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt1"])
df["dt2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt2"])
df["dt3"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt3"])
```

As you can see here, for the column with two datetimes and the column with a datetime and NaT, it is converted into an object (datetime.date), but when all values are NaT, it remains as a datetime64[ns] type. Is there a way to convert to a date type that will be consistent for columns with all NaT as well?

[image: dates]

Comment: `dt.date` will almost return `object` dtype for you because `datetime.date` is an object to Pandas. I'd use `dt.normalize()` so the output always has `datetime64[ns]` dtype.

Comment: Right I understand that, but I don't want a datetime I want a date. The reason is I need to compare these values to another data source where they are stored as dates, and I don't want to need to worry about casting stuff downstream, I should be able to consistently know I'm saving with a date type right?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, `object` dtype is the most generic one. If you want it to be `object` dtype, then just chain `to_datetime.dt.date` with `.astype('object')`. That said, your underlying data is still `pd.NaT`, not `datetime.date`, and you still need to handle them separately. Converting data type doesn't seem to solve the consistency problem.

Comment: So the end goal is these are going into parquet format and I won't be reading with pandas I'll be reading with bigquery. Pyarrow maps datetime.date to a date format when writing to parquet, while it maps datetimes to timestamp type. I'd like to be able to write a parquet with a date type.

Comment: My question is what pyarrow maps `pd.NaT` to, because it's still there. If it handles `pd.NaT` just fine, then chaining with `astype('object')` solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I realised too late that this is explicitly about `to_parquet()`. I am leaving my answer anyway as I stumbled upon the the somewhat generic title trying to solve the same problem with `to_sql()`*

What worked for me in the end is to pass dtype to the `DataFrame.to_sql()` function. This allows to work with datetime while transforming the data, and then cast it to date at the end by passing `sqlalchemy.Date` in a map:

```
import sqlalchemy

df = pd.DataFrame({'Event':     ['Concert', 'Market', 'Fair'], 
                   'Startdate': ['20-12-2022', '21-12-2022', '22-12-2022'],
                   'Enddate':   ['20-12-2022', None, '26-12-2022']
                  })

df['Startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Startdate'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Enddate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Enddate'], format='%d-%m-%Y')

sqa_types = {'Startdate': sqlalchemy.Date, 'Enddate': sqlalchemy.Date}
df.to_sql(name='tablename', con=myConnection, dtype=sqa_types)
```